# Generics in Rust: cannot divide `<T as Add>::Output` by `{float}`

Tags: generics, rust

I'm learning generics in Rust. I created a simple use case of a trapezium structure with a function to calculate its area. Please consider the following example below:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Trapezium<T> {
    a: T,
    b: T,
    h: T,
    area: T,
    perimeter: T,
}

fn calc_area<T: std::ops::Add>(a: T, b: T, h: T) -> T {

    return (a+b)/2.0/h;
}

fn main() {

    let mut t = Trapezium {a: 3.1, b: 6.9, h: 2.5, area: 0.0, perimeter: 0.0};
    t.area    = calc_area(t.a, t.b, t.h);
    println!("t: {:?}", t);
}
```

I have a problem in the `calc_area` function due to a division by a `float64`. Please find my compilation error below:

```
Compiling geometric v0.1.0 (/Users/mabalenk/repo/git/rustup/src/geometric)
error[E0369]: cannot divide `<T as Add>::Output` by `{float}`
  --> src/main.rs:12:17
   |
12 |     return (a+b)/2.0/h;
   |            -----^--- {float}
   |            |
   |            <T as Add>::Output
   |
help: consider further restricting the associated type
   |
10 | fn calc_area<T: std::ops::Add>(a: T, b: T, h: T) -> T where <T as Add>::Output: Div<f64> {
   |                                                       ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0369`.
error: could not compile `geometric` (bin "geometric") due to previous error
```

I'm concerned by the suggestion of adding a `where <T as Add>::Output: Div<f64>` clause. The `Div<f64>` is not making it generic any more. Plus adding this clause doesn't help to compile the code. Also it does make the source code very cluttered.

Can you please suggest an elegant 'textbook' solution to make my basic example work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`T: std::ops::Add` ensures that you can compute `a+b`, but it doesn't allow you to compute `/2.0/h`. You need at least `T: std::ops::Div` so that you can compute `/h`, plus some way to allow the `/2.0`.

The compiler is trying to suggest one way that would allow the division by two, but there are others. One of the simplest since you already need `T: std::ops::Div` anyway is to ensure that you can construct a `T` from `2.0`, which can be expressed as `T: From<f32>`.

Moreover since your function returns a value of type `T`, you also need to tell the compiler that all those operations return `T`s.

Full example:

```
fn calc_area<T>(a: T, b: T, h: T) -> T
where
    T: std::ops::Add<Output = T>,
    T: std::ops::Div<Output = T>,
    T: From<f32>,
{
    return (a+b)/2.0.into()/h;
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=bee6e83baade837c58624c29f94323ae)

Comment: Thank you for a detailed explanation! Is there a way to make `T: From<f32>` generic? Also what does `2.0.into()` do?

Comment: `T: From<f32>` is already generic, and `2.0.into()` converts `2.0` (which has type `f32`) into type `T` so that we can use the `T` implementation of `Div` for the division by two.

Comment: I would also remove the explicit `std::ops::Add` from the function signature leaving only `calc_area<T>`. `std::ops::Add` is already listed below in the `where` clause. It is called a 'bound'. Am I right?

Comment: @mabalenk good point, the `<T: std::ops::Add>` came from a copy-paste…

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to write the code even more generically than in Jmb's answer, by making use of [`num_traits::One`](https://docs.rs/num-traits/latest/num_traits/identities/trait.One.html) to build up the number 2 you need. This way, the code will even work for integers (with rounding down, of course).

```rust
use std::ops;

fn calc_area<T>(a: T, b: T, h: T) -> T
where
    T: ops::Add<Output = T> + ops::Div<Output = T> + num_traits::One,
{
    let two = T::one() + T::one();
    return (a + b) / two / h;
}
```

When you want to write generic numeric code, don't hesitate to use [`num_traits`](https://crates.io/crates/num-traits) — that's what it's there for. You could use the stronger bound `Num` in place of all the individual ops:

```rust
fn calc_area<T: num_traits::Num>(a: T, b: T, h: T) -> T {
    let two = T::one() + T::one();
    return (a + b) / two / h;
}
```